# C++ Include Relative Paths Broken

Tags: c++, makefile, path, include, relative-path

I am currently working on a large-scale financial application.

There are multiple modules that are compiled separately and then combined in a higher-level makefile.

Due to poor design, a lot of the header files include lots of local includes.

<s>My problem is, when I include `/src/equity/pdeModels/EqUtil.H` inside my current source file `/src/rwBatch/calcVol.C`, all the includes at the start of EqUtil.H start to break, giving an error:  `../../equity/pdeModels/EqUtil.H:15:30: fatal error: ulbase/SpotPrice.H: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`</s>

`rwBatch` and the `equity` folder are separately compiled and linked together later. Is this a problem with the makefile? Or how should I go about resolving this?

Indepth example:

/src/Module1/file1.C
/src/Module2/folderA/file2.H
/src/Module2/folderB/file3.H

When I write `#include "../folderA/file2.H"` in file1.C there are errors because of file2.H.
 At the start of file2.H there are several includes, for example `#include "/folderB/file3.H"` which, when compiled in file1.C leads to  `fatal error: /folderB/file3.H: No such file or directory compilation terminated`.

Is this a problem with the makefile? Or how should I go about resolving this?

Comment: Might be solvable by adding a new include search path to the compiler command line, but hard to tell with this little information. Can you provide a more detailed example? A full-on [mcve]is tricky for a question like this (because we likely don't have your build system to experiment with) but see how close you can get.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the header files, or just the makefiles?

Comment: @Beta I could change both

Comment: @user4581301 I updated the post with a more detailed example

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a path in an `#include` statement is almost always a bad idea. It takes information needed by the builder but not by the code, and locks it into the code.

As long as there are no name collisions (e.g. `folderA/file3.h` and `folderB/file3.h`) you can simply remove those paths. Change these:

```
// file1.c:
#include "../folderA/file2.H"

// file2.H:
#include "/folderB/file3.H"
```

to these:

```
// file1.c:
#include "file2.H"

// file2.H:
#include "file3.H"
```

And in your makefile (or other build system):

```
gcc -I/src/Module2/folderA -I/src/Module2/folderB -c /src/Module1/file1.C -o /wherever/file1.o
```

If there *are* name collisions, and you have a module that depends on two headers with the same name, you have some options. The simplest -- and probably best -- is to rename one or both of the headers. If you really must, you can put paths into the `#include` statements, but the paths should reflect the directory structure you use, not the other way around.